# Do I need to set options for SSLSocket again?

Tags: java, sockets, ssl

I have a Java project where, first, I open a simple socket and apply some options to it, namely:

```
private void setSocketOptions () {
    try {
        socket.setTcpNoDelay(config.SOTCPnoDelay());
        socket.setSoTimeout(config.SOTimeout());
        socket.setKeepAlive(config.SOKeepAlive());
        socket.setReceiveBufferSize(config.SOReceiveBufSize());
        socket.setSendBufferSize(config.SOSendBufSize());
    }
    catch (IOException e) {
        throw new PGError(e, "couldn't set set socket options");
    }
}
```

Then, if a user wants to use SSL, I create an instance of `SSLSocket` and replace the `socket` field with it:

```
    final SSLContext sslContext = getSSLContext();
    final SSLSocket sslSocket = (SSLSocket) sslContext.getSocketFactory().createSocket(
            socket,
            config.host(),
            config.port(),
            true
    );
    sslSocket.setUseClientMode(true);
    sslSocket.setEnabledProtocols(SSLProtocols);
    sslSocket.startHandshake();
    socket = sslSocket;
```

The question is: do I need to apply the socket options above to the `sslSocket` instance? I think that the `sslSocket` should reuse them, but I'd like to be sure.

Comment: The SSLSocket does all its I/O through your configured socket, so you don’t need to reconfigure.

Comment: But of course there's nothing stopping you from calling your `setSocketOptions()` method again ...